# Modeling the probability of observing $N$ photons in an interval of time

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

Coherent beams produced by lasers follow Poissonian statistics, that is, the number of photons passing through the cross-section of the beam per unit time can be described by the Poisson distribution.  As such, the waiting time, $T$, between photons follows an exponential distribution.

Squeezed light, on the other hand, has "sub-exponential" waiting times.  We may define a squeezed version of the exponential distribution as follows. Let $H,s>0$, $X\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(1/s,H)$ (shape-rate parameterization), and $T=X^{1/s}$. Then $T$ follows a squeezed exponential distribution
$$
f_T(t)=\frac{H^{1/s}}{\Gamma(1+1/s)}e^{-Ht^s}.
$$
Note that when $s=1$, we recover the exponential density function.

Now let $N$ denote the number of photons passing through the cross-section of a squeezed light beam over a a time period $t_0$.  The probability of observing zero photons is easy to work out:
$$
\mathsf P(N=0)=\mathsf P(T>t_0)=\tilde\Gamma(1/s,Ht_0^s),
$$
where $\tilde\Gamma$ is the regularized upper incomplete gamma function
$$
\tilde\Gamma(a,z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_z^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}\mathrm dt.
$$

However, the probability of observing exactly one photon during the time period $t\in[0,t_0]$ is
$$
\mathsf P(N=1)=\mathsf P(T_1\leq t_0,T_2>t_0-T_1)=\int_0^{t_0}\frac{H^{1/s}}{\Gamma(1+1/s)}e^{-Hx^s}\tilde\Gamma(1/s,H(t_0-x)^s)\ \mathrm dx,
$$
which is not so nice.

Probabilities for larger $N$ can be further written in terms of double, triple, quadruple, etc., integrals.  This of course is not very useful for computation.  I wonder if a closed-form solution (a solution in terms of known special functions) to the integral defining $\mathsf P(N=1)$ can be achieved as it may shed light on how to obtain solutions to the integrals for larger $N$.

Comment: Can you provide the exact definition of the regularized upper incomplete gamma function? I've never encountered your notation..
Also, is $H$ a real number? If you have other representation of the $P(N=1)$ integral, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Zacky I added the definition to the post. Yes, $H$ and $s$ are real and positive. I will see what other representations for $\mathsf P(N=1)$ I can come up with. Right now I have no others.